# Regex naming scheme python

Tags: python, regex

Im trying to check a filename using regular expressions in Python. The name should have the following scheme or structure: '**CB_00xx_D0xx_Vxxxxx00_Vxxxxxx00_Vxx**' where x is a numeral between 0 and 9. Could this be done in one Regular expression?
and How ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. However you should try something before asking here. Please, read [ask]

Comment: is that `0` zero or `O` or O

Answer (score 0):

Well follow this

```
import re
regBuilder = re.compile('^CB_00\d\d_D0\d\d_V\d{5}00_V\d{6}00_V\d\d$')
if regBuilder.match("CB_0045_D056_V5678900_V12345600_V34") :
     print ('Match')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
m = re.match(r'CB_00\d\d_D0\d\d_V\d{5}00_V\d{5}00_V\d\d$', your_filename)
if m:
     print('Yay!')
```